# Android Studio 3.2 's exception when preview layout have custom view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.2

Android Studio **3.2** when preview layout ;
it seems that is confused when resolve resources's id in **more then one module**.
my customView in another module.
by the way, Android Studio **3.1.4** is working

> Could not resolve resource value: 0x7F0F0117. Or the resolved value
>   was not of type layout as expected.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve resource value: 0x7F0F0117. Or the resolved value was not of type layout as expected.
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1117)
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1093)
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getLayout(Resources_Delegate.java:497)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1155)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
at com.******.widget.HotKeyEditView.initView(HotKeyEditView.java:44)
at com.******.widget.HotKeyEditView.<init>(HotKeyEditView.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:401)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:184)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:142)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:229)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:421)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:432)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:336)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:162)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:900)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:859)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:327)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:386)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:450)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:590)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I was having odd errors with 3.2 as well, so I recreated my project from a new 3.2 blank template and pasted all my code and resources in. This resolved my issues.

Comment: Seems to be an Android Studio bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117486771

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120687935

This should be fixed in 3.3.2 which we'll be releasing soon.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the comments, [this is a bug in Android Studio](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117486771). I found a workaround for this issue, namely create a layout in the app module that simply includes the layout from the lib module that had trouble rendering. Then you can edit the lib layout and to see the changes go to the app layout that includes it.